# Como gerar Thumbnail usando MediaToolKit

Tags: c#, asp.net

Preciso gerar um thumbnail apartir de um video ao subir ele para minha aplicação, gostaria de uma explicação de como usar o pacote [MediaToolKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaToolkit/1.0.0.3) para fazer isso, desde já eu agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para instalar o pacote, eu recomendo baixá-lo pelo nuget, mas isso é questão de preferência.

> PM> Install-Package MediaToolkit

Depois de baixar e referenciar o pacote no projeto, é possível gerar uma *thumb* usando o método [`GetThumbnail()` da classe `Engine`](https://github.com/AydinAdn/MediaToolkit/blob/master/MediaToolkit%20src/MediaToolkit/Engine.cs#L109)

```
using MediaToolkit;
using MediaToolkit.Model;
using MediaToolkit.Options; 

/* Resto do código */

private void SalvarThumb(string caminhoVideo)
{
    var caminhoThumb  = Path.Combine("C:\DestinoThumb", "nomeArquivo.jpg");
    var inputFile  = new MediaFile { Filename = caminhoVideo };
    var outputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = thumbPath };

    using (var engine = new Engine())
    {
        engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);

        // A propriedade Seek define em qual momento do vídeo você pretende tirar o "snapshot"
        var options = new ConversionOptions { Seek = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(05) };
        engine.GetThumbnail(inputFile, outputFile, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, codigo muito simples de entender. irei testar mas tenho certeza que ira funcionar, ja irei selecionar como resposta correta, obrigado mesmo.